# SoapUI/maven: No HTML report

Tags: maven, soapui

I have SoapUI project, which I run via maven.

I want to make html report after each running. I want all errors to be in the report if they occurred.

I made following POM file for all this this:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    `enter code here`<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.smartbear.samples</groupId>
        <artifactId>soapui-maven3-plugin</artifactId>

        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>Maven 3 SoapUI Sample</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
                <name>JBoss.org Maven repository</name>
                <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
                <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven3/</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                    <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.2</version>

                    <dependencies>
                        ...some dependencies

                    </dependencies>

           <configuration>
                        <projectFile>${project.basedir}/test-project.xml</projectFile>
                        <outputFolder>${project.basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                        <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                        <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                        <printReport>true</printReport>                         
              </configuration>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>1st project </id>
                            <phase>test-compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>                        
                        </execution>        
                    </executions>

                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <reporting>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>       
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>   
    </project>
```

But after run project via mvn - no html report, just .txt and .xml files in /surefire-reports folder.

What I should fix in my POM?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html):

> reportFormat : Sets formats for created report. **Pro only.**